# Can't seem to get my jQuery to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I need another set of eyes on this. When I use jsfiddle everything worked but for some reason I can't get it to operate in Dreamweaver. I get no errors or the like. I'm going to try again later because it may be that my Dreamweaver is malfunctioning. Look over the code and tell me what you think please. Obviously this is a work in progress. The code is below.

***HTML***

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Portfolio.css" />
                <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="PortfolioControl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <title>Home Page</title>
    </head>

<body>

<!-- CONTENT //-->
    <table align="center" id="navTable">
        <tr>
<!-- NAME AND LOGO //-->
            <td colspan='2' id="titleBar">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="navButton">
                    <p>Home</p>
                </div>
            </td>
<!-- RIGHT SIDE //-->
            <td id="rightSide" rowspan='5'>
                <p>replaced on ready</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="navButton">
                    <p>Art</p>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="navButton">
                    <p>Projects</p>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="navButton">
                    <p>Blog</p>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="navButton">
                    <p>Contact</p>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

***CSS***

```
body {
    background: #000000;
}

/* TITLE */
#titleBar {
    height: 100px;
}

/* DYNAMIC RIGHT SIDE*/
#rightSide {
    width: 620px;
    border-left: 2px solid white;
    padding: 15px;
}

#rightSide p {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

/* MAIN PAGE TABLE */
#navTable {
    margin-top:200px;
    width: 800px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #000000;
}
#navTable td {
    padding-right: 15px;
}

/* NAV BUTTONS */
.navButton p {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.navButton p:hover {
    color: #FF7600;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    //create a p
    var yay = $('<p>Yay</p>');

    $('rightSide').append(yay);
});
```

Comment: `$('#rightSide').append(yay);`

Comment: ummmm. that ain't no Java

Comment: I see you mistook Javascript for Java. You should totally drop that and try jQuery

Comment: @scrblnrd3 it is jQuery !

Comment: I haven't seen layout table in a long time.

Comment: Can you post the jsfiddle link? Does it also have the `$('rightSide')` typo (missing the `#` before the ID)?

Comment: Just for a bit of clarification, `$('rightside')` attempts to select all elements in the DOM of type `rightside` (like `div` or `a`). But to my knowledge no browsers have that element type.

Comment: Here's the jsfiddle link...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q5Skn/

Answer (score 1):

It is because in your jQuery function you have not identified the correct selector for your rightSide element.

jQuery $('') selector works off the same constructs as CSS, therefore you are missing the ID identifier before rightSide.

`$('#rightSide').append(yay);`

should work.

Comment: That was definitely a typo and probably one of the problems but putting in the correct identifier is still not working :( Any other suggestions?

Comment: By not working in Dreamweaver, how do you mean? In Live View? Have you tried running the page on your local web server and see if that works? If the above works in JSFiddle with the typo corrected (as it did for me when I tested it), it should technically work on web. Dreamweaver may be configured to not run JavaScript, or it is not pulling in your linked jQuery library. Try running it locally and see if it is working in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the reason it wasn't working...
Apparently I needed to download jQuery and use the local file instead of trying to link out to Google. I'm pretty sure I've linked out to the Google APIs before so I'm not sure why I couldn't this time. Anyway, thank you everyone for your help.